# cypress to test handsontable

Tags: handsontable, cypress

I am using cypress for my e2e test. There is a screen where i use [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/examples?headers). It  resembles an excel sheet. I could't write contents to its cells using cypress, since the cell is actually just a `td`, but internally it gets mapped to a `textarea` while editing.

Can some one provide a test using cypress to enter text it its cells.

I tied the following, but it did not work.

```
cy.get('.handsontable tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').dblclick().type('test');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to type in a cell with the following spec.

```
context('handsontable', () => {
  it('handsontable', () => {
    cy.visit("https://handsontable.com/examples?headers");
    cy.get('.handsontable tbody > :nth-child(10) > :nth-child(2)').click().click().get('.handsontableInput').type('test');
  })
})
```

For some reason `dblclick()` didn't work.

Comment: Clicking to invoke edit mode is the way to go. Changing text directly as per other answer is not possible for a user to do, so that test is invalid (even though it succeeds).

Answer (score 1):

If type is not possible, you could try with pasting of `text` in the identified field as  below;  I have run the below test and I could paste `AUD` in the `currency` column of first td row. I am using cypress version `3.1.2` on Windows 10 OS, with Chrome 70 test runner

```
describe("Cypress test on handsontable", function() {
  it("Some test on handsontable", function() {
  cy.visit("https://handsontable.com/examples?headers")
  cy.get('.handsontable tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5)').then($td => {
      $td.text('AUD');
     });
   });
});
```

[image]